# How can I query for all values of a custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query

Suppose I have a Custom Taxonomy "Fruits". I want to query for all the values available eg. Oranges, Apples, Mangos etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_terms($taxonomy, $args)`

```
$terms = get_terms('Fruits');
```

[Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)